# "-webkit-filter" doesn't work in firefox 41.0.2

Tags: css, firefox

I have a css property for a disabled button as follows.

```
.btn-disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
    color:#cecece !Important;
    -webkit-filter: opacity(50%)    
}
```

I get the needed effect in chrome, but not in firefox. Is there a way to achieve the same in firefox,chrome,saffari through the same css properties?

Comment: Firefox doesn’t require a prefix for `filter`, just use it standard-compliant. Of course, there’s also `opacity` as a stand-alone property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need use prefix for firefox **-moz-**, this is for all browsers:

```
.btn-disabled {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; /* IE 8 */
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);  /* IE 5-7 */
    -moz-opacity: 0.5; /* Netscape - firefox */
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5; /* Safari 1.x */
    opacity: 0.5; /* Good browsers */
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

You can see that [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/).

Answer (score 1):

Vendor prefixed properties are **experimental** features in **specific browser engines**.

Firefox is built around Gecko, not Webkit, so experimental Webkit features will not work in it.

Avoid using vendor prefixed properties on the open web (unless you are writing sites where the point is to experiment instead of being robust).

Firefox has supported [the non-prefixed version](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility) for quite some time.

If you really want decent browser support, use the [opacity property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) instead. It has support back to Firefox 1.

Answer (score 0):

simply use firefox -moz- prefix,

```
.btn-disabled{   
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
    color:#cecece !Important;
    -webkit-filter: opacity(50%);
    -moz-filter: opacity(50%);
    filter: opacity(50%);
}
```